# How to create a class to define a CSV file layout including a header?

Tags: python, export-to-csv, namedtuple

I would like to create an approach where I can define the structure of a CSV file (obvious extension to excel should follow) where there is a row definition as well has the header.  In this approach a simple re-ordering of the definition will move the columns in the output.

My first attempt was to use a `namedtuple`.  Actually handled most of my needs but I can't create an empty row the populate it as needed.  I tried to use a `recordclass` but have much the same problem.

My output file might have > 30 columns so it gets very sloppy to have to create a new instance with a bunch of `None`s.  I also want to be able to add a column to the structure without having to update the `__init__`, etc.

My idea pseudo-code (using `namedtuple`s for illustration) would be:

```
class TableRow(namedtuple(TableRow, "id name password hostip"))
    __slots__ = ()


class TableRowHeader:
    def __init__(self):
        header = TableRow()
        header.id = 'ID'
        header.name = "Name"
        header.password = "Password"
        header.hostip = "Host IP"


class OutputTable():
    def __init__(self):
        self.header = TableRowHeader()
        self.rows = list()

    def add(self, new_row):
        # Example assumes new_row is an instance of TableRow
        self.rows.append(new_row)

    def to_csv(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as csv_file:
            # creating a csv writer object
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

            # writing the fields
            csv_writer.writerow(self.header)

            for row in sorted(self.rows):
                csv_writer.writerow(row)  


outtable = OutputTable()
row = TableRow()
row.id = 1
row.name = 'Matt'
row.hostip = '10.0.0.1'
row.password = 'obvious'      
outtable.add(row)

outtable.to_csv('./example.csv')
```

I like the pattern but can't figure out a clean way to handle this in Python.

Comment: Is this for educational/learning purposes?

Comment: Well always learning but its not for a course I am taking if that is the question.  I am new to Python, coming from Java.  I built a class for this in Java that I have used for years and could build another in Python but was interested to see if I was just re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I ask because Python has libraries for working with Excel, and using a class for this seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like that?

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

TableRowShort = namedtuple('TableRow', "id name password hostip")
TableRowFull = namedtuple('TableRowFull', "id name password hostip description source admin_name")


class TableRowOptional:
    def __init__(self, id, name, password=None, hostip=None, description=None, source=None, admin_name=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.hostip = hostip
        self.description = description
        self.source = source
        self.admin_name = admin_name


class OutputTable():
    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = []
        self.rows = list()

    def add(self, row):
        if hasattr(row, '_asdict'):
            value = row._asdict()
        elif hasattr(row, '__dict__'):
            value = row.__dict__
        elif isinstance(row, dict):
            value = row
        else:
            raise ValueError('Not supported row type: {}'.format(type(row)))

        for header in value.keys():
            if header not in self.headers:
                self.headers.append(header)

        self.rows.append(value)

    def to_csv(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as csv_file:
            # creating a csv writer object
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

            # writing the fields
            csv_writer.writerow(self.headers)

            for row in self.rows:
                csv_writer.writerow([row.get(header, None) for header in self.headers])


outtable = OutputTable()
outtable.add(TableRowShort(1, 'Matt', 'obvious', '10.0.0.1'))
outtable.add(TableRowFull(2, 'Maria', 'obvious as usual', '10.1.0.1', 'some description', 'localnet', 'super_admin'))
outtable.add(TableRowOptional(3, 'Maria', hostip='10.1.0.1', description='some description', source='localnet'))
outtable.add({
    'id': 1337,
    'name': 'hacker',
    'hostip': '127.0.0.1',
    'extra': "I've hacked you guys lol!",
})

outtable.to_csv('./example.csv')
```

This solution provides you interface to store some "prepared namedtuples, normal objects (using `__dict__` interface) and raw dict objects as rows. It manages CSV headers automatically based on provided rows structures :)

Looks pretty clear & useful to me. What do you think?

Output CSV

```
# > cat example.csv
id,name,password,hostip,description,source,admin_name,extra
1,Matt,obvious,10.0.0.1,,,,
2,Maria,obvious as usual,10.1.0.1,some description,localnet,super_admin,
3,Maria,,10.1.0.1,some description,localnet,,
1337,hacker,,127.0.0.1,,,,I've hacked you guys lol!
```

Comment: That is sort of what I have now.  The downside is that if the user wants to add a column or re-order the output order I need to make changes in 3 places and when you have a lot of columns the possibility of error becomes high.  Also just a pain.

Comment: ah, so you want a solution to store row columns and  "any headers based on rows dynamically processed", right?

Comment: Sounds about right yes.  I want to isolate the data management from the physical output.  So the table layout doesn't impact how I build the rows.

Comment: @MatthewDoering check it now

Comment: Much closer to what I was thinking yes, thank you.  I think if I use a recordclass or a wrapper that allows me to assign values to an object then have that class build the namedtuple I'll have what I need.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The initial code can be rewriten as follows using `recordclass` library:

```
import csv
from recordclass import make_dataclass

TableRow = make_dataclass(
            'TableRow', 
            "id name password hostip description source admin_name",
            defaults=5*(None,),
            iterable=True)

class OutputTable():
    def __init__(self):
        self.header = TableRow(*TableRow.__fields__)
        self.rows = list()

    def add(self, new_row):
        # Example assumes new_row is an instance of TableRow
        self.rows.append(new_row)

    def to_csv(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as csv_file:
            # creating a csv writer object
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

            # writing the fields
            csv_writer.writerow(self.header)

            for row in sorted(self.rows):
                csv_writer.writerow(row)

outtable = OutputTable()
outtable.add(TableRow(1, 'Matt', 'obvious', '10.0.0.1'))
outtable.add(TableRow(2, 'Maria', 'obvious as usual', '10.1.0.1', 'some description', 'localnet', 'super_admin'))
outtable.add(TableRow(3, 'Maria', hostip='10.1.0.1', description='some description', source='localnet'))

outtable.to_csv('./example.csv')
```

The result will be:

```
id,name,password,hostip,description,source,admin_name
1,Matt,obvious,10.0.0.1,,,
2,Maria,obvious as usual,10.1.0.1,some description,localnet,super_admin
3,Maria,,10.1.0.1,some description,localnet,
```